# Морфологический разбор "в последний раз встрепенулась"

Tags: морфология

Здравствуйте! Об'ясните пожалуйста морфологическую роль слова "раз" в предложении "И та наконец свистнула слабо, незвучно, в последний раз встрепенулась, слегка пошевелив листьями вокруг себя, и заснула."

Answer (score 2):

В последний раз. Слово РАЗ употреблено в значении существительного - как и существительное, оно имеет при себе согласованное определение.

ЗНАЧЕНИЕ. Указывает место какого-л. действия, случая и т.п. в ряду других подобных, бывших ранее, повторяющихся действий, случаев и т.п.

Отложим разговор до следующего раза. Всякий раз.В другой раз. На первый раз прощается. На этот раз довольно. На сей раз поверим. В прошлый раз мы договорились обо всём. Раз от разу(от случая к случаю). В последний раз говорю.

Comment: Спасибо. Дочка так же ответила на уроке, а учитель говорит, что это наречие и отвечает на вопросы как, каким образом, когда. Мы были в замешательстве.

Comment: Очень многие вопросы решаются с помощью толковых словарей. Приведенная информация взята из Грамоты-ру - этот сайт в наибольшей степени отражает академическую точку зрения на орфографию и грамматику. Думаю, что и для учительницы такая ссылка будет значимым аргументом. Что касается  вопросов КАК, КАКИМ ОБРАЗОМ и др, то на эти вопросы могут отвечать не только наречия, но и существительные в роли обстоятельства, например: говорить с восторгом, взлететь стайкой, слушать  без удивления, смотреть в недоумении.

Comment: Согласна,"раз"может быть наречием в следующем предложении: Раз пошёл я погулять. Когда? - раз(однажды).В последний раз - обстоятельство, выраженное сочетанием существительного с прилагательным